# .htaccess: Rewrite rule for URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How to use the `.htaccess` to change the url 
`https://example/userdetail.php?pn=1&order=user_id&sort=ASC&search=null`

to
`https://example/userdetail/1/user_id/ASC/null/`

Comment: Is that url the only rewrite needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hava MVC then you can used like that:

```
  Url: 
     <a href="/controllerName/1/user_id/ASC/null">
```

Make Route, an then

```
  Controller:

     class controllerName extends Controller {

        public function index($ph, $order, $sort, $search){

          }
     }
```